# Enable Emacs-like keybindings scheme for all QT applications

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, qt

As for GTK apps under Gnome environment it's possible to set all applications to use Emacs-like input scheme:

```
$ gconftool --set -t string /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme Emacs
$ gconftool --get /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme
Emacs
```

I wonder if it's possible to adjust input for all QT apps in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

KDE doesn't use registry tools such as `gconf` everything done by system settings, but you can try `kwriteconfig` to set global environment for KDE applications. But I'm not sure either. You can read [Hidden KDE Options and Features](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Hidden-KDE-Options-and-Features-53213.shtml) tutorial.

Comment: That won't help him if Qt doesn't support Emacs key bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Unity:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Emacs"
```

Comment: It's a solution for GTK apps, not for Qt ones.

Answer (score -2):

Not so obvious solution for GTK apps in Cinnamon:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Emacs"
```